# Bigquery: Filter through JSON array

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having an issue filtering through an json array:

```
WITH table AS ( SELECT *
FROM UNNEST([
  '{"class" : {"students" : [{"type" : "a", "name":"David"},{"type" : "b", "name":"Max"}]}}',
  '{"class" : {"students" : [{"type": "b", "name":"Jamie"},{"type" : "a", "name":"Martin"}]}}',
  '{"class" : {"students" : [{"type" : "a", "name":"Julie"}, {type: "b""name": "Jamie"}]}}'
  ]) AS json_payload)
```

So having a json array I am trying to filter through and get all names that type ='a'. Each array can have just 1 type='a'

My current solution is :

```
SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN JSON_VALUE(json_payload,'$.class.students[0].type') ='a'
    THEN JSON_VALUE(json_payload,'$.class.students[0].name') 
  WHEN JSON_VALUE(json_payload,'$.class.students[1].type') ='a'
    THEN JSON_VALUE(json_payload,'$.class.students[1].name') 
  END AS myName
FROM table
```

I was thinking if there is a better/cleaner solution then this

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> get all names that type ='a'. Each array can have just 1 type='a'

Use below approach

```
select json_extract_scalar(json, '$.name') name 
from your_table,
unnest(json_extract_array(json_payload, '$.class.students')) json
where json_extract_scalar(json, '$.type') = 'a'
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

```
WITH your_table AS ( SELECT *
FROM UNNEST([
  '{"class" : {"students" : [{"type" : "a", "name":"David"},{"type" : "b", "name":"Max"}]}}',
  '{"class" : {"students" : [{"type": "b", "name":"Jamie"},{"type" : "a", "name":"Martin"}]}}',
  '{"class" : {"students" : [{"type" : "a", "name":"Julie"}, {"type": "b", "name": "Jamie"}]}}'
  ]) AS json_payload
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One small addition, make sure to add any value as string even they are integers. BigQuery didn't accept integers in comparison to json values.